# Unable to bind class to Formgroup in Angular

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have a user registration page and i am trying to map the User class to html using formgroup in angular, but  Cannot read properties of the class, I have added the angular html,component.ts and class below. What is it that i am missing

**register.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-7" [formGroup]="userForm">
    <h3>User Registration</h3>
    <br>
    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input-username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="user.userName" id="loginUsername"
                name="loginUsername" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="First Name" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" id="firstName" name="firstName"
                        class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Last Name" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" id="lastName" name="lastName"
                        class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input-email">E-Mail</label>
            <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Email Address" [(ngModel)]="user.email" id="email" name="email"
                class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="control-label" for="input-country">Country</label>
            <p-dropdown [options]="countries" id="input-country" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" optionLabel="name"
                optionValue="code" placeholder="Select a Country"></p-dropdown>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input-password">Password</label>
            <p-password [(ngModel)]="user.password" [toggleMask]="true" id="input-password" name="loginpassword" class="form-control"></p-password>
           
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input-password">Repeat Password</label>
            <p-password [(ngModel)]="user.passConfirm" [toggleMask]="true" id="input-password" name="passConfirm" class="form-control"></p-password>
           
        </div>

        <div id="button-register" class="form-group">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                disabled="disabled" (click)="registerUser()">Register</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">
  
</div>
```

**register.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/api/selectitem';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'

interface Country {
  name: string,
  code: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  public userForm : FormGroup| any;
  countries: Country[] = [];
  data = [];
  user: User|any;
  selectedCountry: Country|any;
  constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    fetch('./assets/commonfiles/countries.json').then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsonData => {
      this.countries = jsonData;
    });
    this.initFormGroups();
  }
  public registerUser(){

  }

  initFormGroups(){
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({user:new FormControl(this.user,[Validators.required])});
  }

}
```

**User.ts**

```
export class User {
  public userName: string | any;
  public password: string | any;
  public email: string | any;
  public firstName: string | any;
  public lastName: string | any;
  public country: string | any;
  public passConfirm: string | any;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CalendarModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ImageModule,
    SocialLoginModule,
    DropdownModule,
    PasswordModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
```

Comment: Why are you using fetch?

Comment: for populating p-dropdown of countries list from json file

Comment: You’re importing HttpClient and then use fetch.. okay..

Answer (score 0):

In component.html file

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
     <div>
        <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="username" matInput type="text">
     </div>
     <div>
        <mat-label>First Name </mat-label>
        <input formControlName="firstName" matInput type="text">
     </div>
    .....
```

In .ts file

```
userForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(private readonly _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.userForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    username: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(5)]),
    firstName: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    ....
  })
}
```

Comment: i could have already done this before i want it to fetch from a seperate class